# Shower mixer handle sticking out too far aesthetically

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

This question is common enough that it should have a place on the stack exchange - so that the best answers can easily be found.

After redoing a bath and waiting to see that everything comes together nicely, things like the following occur:

[image][image]

What are good solutions to alleviate this aesthetic problem?

Comment: The only thing I know of is mounting the assembly further back into the wall and then you end up with a different problem - screw lengths for the cover plate. Of course you might not have depth in the wall to do this.

Answer (score 0):

An answer at [this link](https://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?threads/shower-handle-sticking-out-too-far.17565/page-3) suggested using a lavatory mounting ring

> So I realize this thread has been going on for a couple years now, but I also ran into this problem. I didn't rush in buying the Moen extension plate. I instead went over to the local Home Depot and just started walking around looking for anything that I could mount on the front or back of the mounting plate and with a matching Satin Nickel finish.
>
> In the faucet repair aisle I found a satin nickel lavatory mounting ring that worked quite nicely. Using some adhesive caulk, I glued the included rubber washer to the mounting ring and then the ring to the mounting plate.
>
> The end result looks better than what I would have achieved with a correct install.
>
> [image]

Comment: This solution looks like it covers up the original cover plate mounting screws. This will necessitate breaking out the lavatory mounting ring if the plate ever needs to be removed for repairs.

Comment: What's with that URL being just an IP address? Where does it go? Mighty suspicious.

Comment: @Brad not sure. I simply quoted a relevant answer.

Comment: Please give yourself a check-mark for this answer. That will help others to know it's been resolved and will keep the system from bouncing it to the top of the list every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this link from homedepot for the lavatory mounting ring:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Fontaine-Glass-Vessel-Bathroom-Sink-Mounting-Ring-in-Chrome-LNF-VSMR-CP/202996136

I don't have enough rep to comment yet so feel free to move into the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really helpful if this is discovered after the walls are up, but if someone sees this answer before they embark on the bathroom remodel, they could take this into account when shopping for fixtures.

There are shower fixtures available that are adjustable or that are designed to be used on different wall material thicknesses. For example, my Grohe GrohFlex setup is that way. The valve box is installed in the wall, and there is about an inch of variability in wall thickness that can be accommodated by the fixtures that mount into this valve box. Similar for the hand shower wall elbow, the trim piece is designed to use a long screw that is fastened to the brass elbow piece, and can accommodate various wall thicknesses.